# WHMCS show single ticket reply by last update

Tags: whmcs

I want make a new file to call a ticket replies from db and adding feature for showing a single reply only by reply id or reply time for example if called a URL like

```
history.php?tid=844130&c=1uT0TR8y&lastreply=1222
```

How I can do that?